# Create a Cookie after an jQuery AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cookies

My script is a simple like and dislike buttons (called reactions). It works well but now I want to have a quick cookie created if the vote went through so people can't vote for this particular comment ever again (ie. 1 year.. or when they remove their cookies.)

The entire function works but I am confused on how to add the cookie for each specific comment they have reacted to?

```
(function( $ ) {
    'use strict';

    $( document ).ready(function() {

        $(document).on('click', '.enco-reaction', function(e){

            var data = {
                'action':       'enco_reaction',
                'reaction':     $(this).data('reaction'),
                'comment':      $(this).data('id')
            };

            $.post( 
                ajax_object.ajax_url,
                data,
                function( obj ) {

                    if( obj.error ) {
                        alert( obj.error );
                    } else {
                        $('#enco-reaction-' + obj.reaction + '-' + obj.comment + ' .enco-reaction-count' ).html( obj.value );
                    }
                },
                'json'
            );
        });

    });     

})( jQuery );
```

Comment: It is better to store the vote in the database. Either for registered people or for an IP address. Cookies can be cleared from the browser easily and than people can vote again.

Comment: You can use $.cookie("vote", 1) and $.removeCookie("vote") for storing vote value, but i am also agreed with Gerard if you don't want to allow a user to vote again then save it in database.

Answer (score 0):

Best not to use cookies (I would recommend local storage over cookies for storing data as you can store JSON data better and larger) as it's more used for temporary data.

But for whatever reason you don't want to.

I'd store data in a JSON Object with a user identifier (however you wish to identifier users from each other) and a list of comments id's.

```
{
  "users": {
    "user_ids": {
      "123": [
        "111",
        "222",
        "333"
      ],
      "456": [
        "111",
        "222",
        "333"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and just JSON.stringify() before storing it in either cookies or local storage.

Answer (score 0):

as per people's recommendations, I've opted for a simple table in my database and I log ip, comment_id, date, etc. and then I just retrieve the last date for a given IP and check.

thanks!